# How to solve the decoding and cant not open BingMap in Luciad AIXM Viewer 5.0?

Tags: bing-maps, decoding, luciad-aixm-5-viewer

I am using [Luciad AIXM 5 Viewer](http://www.luciad.com/solutions/luciad-aixm-viewer).

I'm unable to open the BingMap and solve this decoding problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain Bing Credentials before you can use BingMaps, as explained in the user guide of the AIXM Viewer:

> 4.1.1 Loading Bing Maps layers
>
> Bing Maps is a web mapping service provided by Microsoft, offering traditional road maps, aerial photo views, and searching capabilities. The Luciad AIXM 5 Viewer allows you to connect to Bing Maps, and load Bing Maps layers with roads and aerial imagery.
>
> Supplying Bing Maps credentials
>
> Before you can connect to the Bing Maps servers, you need to obtain a Bing Maps license key.
>   The Bing Maps portal at http://www.bingmapsportal.com allows you to
>   create a Bing Maps account and one or more Bing Maps keys. You must
>   enter the obtained Bing Maps ID in the Luciad AIXM 5 Viewer before you
>   can load Bing Maps layers. Go to Data | Bing Maps | Edit
>   Credentials..., and fill in the ID in the Bin Maps Credentials dialog
>   box. Click OK to save the ID in the Luciad AIXM 5 Viewer.